# Using Wget to download PDF files from a site that requires cookies to be set

Tags: pdf, wget

I want to access a newspaper site and then download their epaper copies (in PDF). The site requires me to login using my email address and password and then it permits me to access those PDF URLs.

I'm having trouble 'setting my session' in wget. When I login into the site from my browser, it sets two cookie values:

```
UserID=abc@gmail.com
Password=12345
```

I tried:

```
wget --post-data "UserID=abc@gmail.com&Password=12345" http://epaper.abc.com/login.aspx
```

However, that just downloaded the login page and saved it locally

The FORM on the login page has two fields:

```
txtUserID
txtPassword
```

and radiobuttons like this:

```
<input id="rbtnManchester" type="radio" checked="checked" name="txtpub" value="44">
```

Another button:

```
<input id="rbtnLondon" type="radio" name="txtpub" value="64">
```

If I post this to the login.aspx page, I get the same output

```
wget --post-data "txtUserID=abc@gmail.com&txtPassword=12345&txtpub=44" http://epaper.abc.com/login.aspx
```

If I do:

--save-cookies abc_cookies.txt

it doesnt seem to have anything other than the default content.

For the last if I do --debug as well it says:

```
...
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=05kphcn4hjmblq45qgnjoe41; path=/; HttpOnly
...
Stored cookie epaper.abc.com -1 (ANY) / <session> <insecure> [expiry none] ASP.NET_SessionId 05kphcn4hjmblq45qgnjoe41
Length: 107253 (105K) [text/html]
Saving to: `login.aspx'
...
Saving cookies to abc_cookies.txt.
```

However, abc_cookies.txt shows ONLY the following:

```
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2011-08-16 08:03:05.
# Edit at your own risk.
```

Comment: Hmm, I answered your crosspost over at http://superuser.com/questions/323971/using-wget-to-download-pdf-files-from-a-site-that-requires-cookies-to-be-set

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, did you try using querystring variables (not too secure, obviously)?

```
wget "http://epaper.abc.com/login.aspx?UserID=abc@gmail.com&Password=12345"
```

You might have to escape the special characters depending on your shell / OS.